# How can I write a program that has an input of n and then calculates the sum of n numbers that the user enters?

Tags: c

I've written this so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 0, i = 0, sum = 0, a = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (i <= n);
    {
        scanf("\n%d", &a);
        sum = sum + a;
        i++;
    }   
    printf("%d", sum);
}
```

but when I enter 8, for example, it won't allow me to add any other numbers.

What's the problem?

Comment: and `i <= n` --> `i < n`

Answer (score 3):

`while (i <= n);` --> `while (i <= n)`.  Drop the `;`.  With the`;`, the `while()` loop never ends and `{ scanf("\n%d", &a);  ...` is never entered.

Suggest using auto formatting - easy to catch problems like this.

---

Also,  to read `n` values use `<` [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350395/how-can-i-write-a-program-that-has-an-input-of-n-and-then-calculates-the-sum-of/40350461#comment67955417_40350395)

```
// while (i <= n)
while (i < n)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Shabnam You can use this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int n, sum = 0, c, value;

  printf("Enter the number of integers you want to add\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("Enter %d integers\n",n);

  for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
   {
     scanf("%d", &value);
     sum = sum + value;
   }

 printf("Sum of entered integers = %d\n",sum);

 return 0;
}
```